# How to copy SSH keys when password authentication is already disabled?

Tags: ssh, passwords, authentication

Once you disable password authentication for SSH login, what is the way to get a new public key into the server?

Background:

I have had this issue forever-and-a-day, I have a server setup in another building. It does not allow password logins and a keys need to be exchanged.

When I'm at home and I've got a new box setup, I can't push the public key to the server. A workaround has always been to have one computer somewhere on the network that allows password logins and leap-frog into the main server. That way I can log into server 2 to get to server 1 to add the public key from guest.

Is the accepted and general way to walk the public key in on a physical key?

The only other way I could think of (and not sure it would work, or whether users would particularly like it) would be to generate a key pair n the server and send the keys to the user (being sure to delete the private key from the server where it was issued). The main issue with this being someone other than the user has had access to the private key.

Answer (score -1):

You should generally not have a password access from anywhere, instead load the key physically onto the machine - this could be via USB, a CD (which has the bonus of you know no one has meddled with it after you've written it) or if you're really hardcore - hand type the whole key in.

If you use the 'password access from another server' route, how do you make sure you've secured ***that*** server enough?

This is also known as 'out of band' communication. You don't share authentication secrets over the same communication as you'll be using them on. As you can never be sure prior to authenticating that they are secure.

Comment: I agree 100%, it's just the issue comes up when I create a new box, reformat, etc. The server is not "easy" to access. Although in typing this, I've just realised, can I save off and keep reusing the same key on next install?

Comment: You're a funny one.  A funny paranoid one, too-long-username-to-type.  How do you propose getting a key onto a server that is physically secured, where even the hoster's admins can't just walz in and twiddle with the physical server?